# Why is my power function not working properly here?

Tags: c, function

I've tried changing variable types but this is still not working.

```
double power(double a, long long b){

    while(b>1){
        a *= a;
        b--;
    }

return a;
}
```

Comment: what does not work?

Comment: This problem is easily diagnosed with a debugger, or even a simple `printf` after the line `a *= a`. Time for you to learn how to use a debugger.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code won't run properly when b>2 because when you're doing a = a*a; the second time it won't be a^3 but a^4 and the next time it will be a^8 and so on.
The right code would be something like this below:

```
double power(double a, long long b){

double k = 1;
    while(b>0){
        k *= a;
        b--;
    }

return k;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You're changing `a` on every iteration. Say you call it like `power(2, 3)`.

First you do `2 * 2` and assign this to `a`, which becomes `4`.

Next iteration, you'll do again `a * a` which is `4 * 4`. Just keep the result in a variable and don't change the arguments:

```
double power(double a, long long b){
    double r = a;
    while(b>1){
        r *= a;
        b--;
    }

    return r;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you are changing the variable `a` and it courses the defects. what you can do instead is

```
double power(double base, double exp)
{
  double result = 1;
  for(int i = 0; i < exp; i++)
  {
    result *= base;
  }
  return result;
}
```